# How to find key of the value in hasmap

Tags: java

I want fetch a key based on the particular value from HashMap

In the following program, I try to find Maximum length of a word in a Sentence. I'm using HashMap to store word as key and length of the word as value.

I try this code :

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test3 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        String sent="EGInnovations located in seven countries in the world";
        String[] words=sent.split(" ");
        int len=0;
        int max=0;
        int min=0;
        int temp=0;
        for(String word : words)
        {

            len=word.length();
            map.put(word, len);
        }

        Iterator it=map.entrySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry str=(Map.Entry)it.next();
            System.out.println(str.getKey()+" "+str.getValue());

            max=(Integer)str.getValue();
            if(max>min)
            {
                temp=max;
                min=max;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(temp);
        System.out.println(map.get(temp));
    }

}
```

I got this output:

```
seven 5
located 7
world 5
EGInnovations 13
the 3
countries 9
in 2

13    //here I got the maximum length
null  //But If I try to get the key of the value(13) It will give "null".
```

Please help for the solution or Give me Idea to get Key of the particular value...

Comment: you will need to iterate it and then compare value and return key

Comment: Why don't you just create a new var tempKey. At the same time as setting temp=max you can set tempKey = str.getKey()

Comment: Can you please Explain with example Naman Gala....

Comment: @kavi have a look at the answer, short and simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new Map which stores `length as key` and `list of value` as value in map.

So whenever you pass a length you can get those values which has that length.

Below program gives you `a map (along with duplicate values like "in" which occurs twice)` which can be used to get max and min value of length as well as its values.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
    String sent = "EGInnovations located in seven countries in the world";
    String[] words = sent.split(" ");
    int len = 0;
    List<String> stringList;
    for (String word : words) {
        len = word.length();

        stringList = map.get(len);
        if (stringList == null) {
            stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
            map.put(len, stringList);
        }
        stringList.add(word);
    }

    if (!map.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Full length map : \n" + map); //Printing full length map
        System.out.println();
        List<Integer> lengthList = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.keySet());

        System.out.println("Minimum Length : " + Collections.min(lengthList));
        System.out.println("Minimum Length Words : " + map.get(Collections.min(lengthList)));

        System.out.println("\nMax Length : " + Collections.max(lengthList));
        System.out.println("Max Length Words : " + map.get(Collections.max(lengthList)));
    }
}
```

**Update:**

For your code you can add below code `after while loop`.

```
//temp contains max length value

it = map.entrySet().iterator();
System.out.println("Max length : " + temp);
while(it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry str=(Map.Entry)it.next();

    if (str.getValue().equals(temp)) {
        System.out.println("Word : "  + str.getKey());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any possibilities to get output from my code, Which is attached previous....

Comment: You will need to iterate your map and then compare your value with max and then get the key.. because you are storing length as value

Answer (score 0):

1.) Use `TreeMap instead of HashMap`, `TreeMap` will automatically sort on the basis of key, which is in this case is length of words. Sorting will be in ascending order.

2.) Using `NavigableMap` to get the last entry, since the last entry will be of max length.

3.) Also you can use  `TreeMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();`, vreate a map with same approach and just access , it will sort in descending order and get the first element `map.descendingMap().entrySet().iterator().next().getValue()`

```
import java.util.NavigableMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class MvelTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NavigableMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
        String sent = "EGInnovations located in seven countries in the world";
        String[] words = sent.split(" ");
        int len = 0;

        for (String word : words) {
            len = word.length();
            map.put(len, word);
        }

         System.out.println("Full Map =>" + map);
         System.out.println("Max Length => " + map.lastEntry().getValue());
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Full Map =>{2=in, 3=the, 5=world, 7=located, 9=countries,13=EGInnovations} 

Max Length => EGInnovations
```